# How to transform record value before update? - Update API expects a different format than fetch API

Tags: react-admin, hasura

I have setup react-admin with Hasura (GraphQL API on Postgres) using the [ra-data-hasura](https://github.com/hasura/graphql-engine/tree/master/community/tools/ra-data-hasura) provider and I ran into an error when trying to update a record in an existing table.

I have this field `tags` with type varchar[] which is delivered by the fetch API in the format: `tags: ["A", "B"]`, but the problem is that the UPDATE API expects the format `tags: "{A,B}"`.

Therefore all UPDATE requests will fail.

I already tried the `parse()` and `format()` functions on the InputField, but they are not changing the initial value of the record. The update will still fail if the `tags` field is left untouched.

This is the API's (Hasura) error message in response to the UPDATE request. (just putting it here so other people might find this post)

```
{
  "path": "$.args.$set",
  "error": "A string is expected for type : _varchar",
  "code": "parse-failed"
}
```

Is there a way to transform the value for `tags` in react-admin without having to modify the API?

Answer (score 0):

You can decorate the Data Provider similarly to the example:
https://marmelab.com/react-admin/DataProviders.html#decorating-your-data-provider-example-of-file-upload

Comment: Thank you. This was what I was looking for!